# Have trouble using GDB to debug MPI code

Tags: c, debugging, gdb, openmpi

I am tring to use GDB to see what's going on about low level OPEN MPI calls. However, I couldn't use GDB to jump into low level library functions in OpenMPI.

I first compiled OpenMPI with tag "--enable-debug --enable-debug-symbols", so library should be compiled with "-g" tag. Then I compile my test code using "mpicc /path/to/my/code -g -o /dest/code". Code is simple shown as below:

```
#include "mpi.h"
#include <stdio.h>

main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int numtasks, rank, dest, source, rc, count, tag=1;
    int buf;
    const int root=0;
    MPI_Status Stat;

    // sleep still GDB attached
    int i = 0;
    char hostname[256];
    gethostname(hostname, sizeof(hostname));
    printf("PID %d on %s ready for attach\n", getpid(), hostname);
    fflush(stdout);
    while (0 == i)
        sleep(5);

    MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numtasks);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

    if(rank == root) {
        buf = 777;
    }

    printf("[%d]: Before Bcast, buf is %d\n", rank, buf);

    MPI_Bcast(&buf, 1, MPI_INT, root, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    printf("[%d]: After Bcast, buf is %d\n", rank, buf);

    MPI_Finalize();
}
```

This code will firstly printout PID for every process, then keep sleep wait for attach. Then I use GDB attach method to attach one of the process. Set break point & reset the value of i will jump out of waiting while loop.

Then, I continue use "s" to step next my code. It supposed to jump into low level library functions like MPI_Init(), MPI_Bcast(). However, GDB will just going to next line and ignore jumping into any function. Neither "bt" could print out backtrace information. But the whole code could run without error.

Could someone found any mistake I made in this whole process? Thanks ahead.

Comment: Normally if `step` doesn't step into a call, it means either there's no debuginfo or you've set a `skip`.  So I would make sure the library really does have debuginfo and that the correct library is being picked up at runtime.